# UDP Not working sometimes

Tags: delphi, connection, udp

Hello currently im using UDP Messages to communicate my program (Made with Delphi Using IdUDPClient and IdUDPServer) on diferent computers in LAN, but yesterday i had a strange issue, one of the computers was unable to receive messages neither could other computers read his messages, All of the programs use the same UDP Port.

The only solution that worked was Restarting the router, but maybe there is an explication on why that happened?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess thats just how UDP works :) Quote from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol):

> UDP uses a simple transmission model with a minimum of protocol mechanism. It has no handshaking dialogues, and thus exposes any unreliability of the underlying network protocol to the user's program. As this is normally IP over unreliable media, there is no guarantee of delivery, ordering or duplicate protection.

Comment: yeah, i suppose, not really a good thing for me :) but well, maybe some1 has another explication if not tomorrow ill choose ur answer =)

Comment: @vexen all is not lost, you can keep a queue of messages and a count, if a message arrives with count=5 and you are expecting count=4, then you can send back a command "re-send me message count=4"

Comment: @ComputerSaysNo The problem is the messages are needed to reconfigure some other programs etc, and until we restart the router we were unable to /send/receive messages to/from that computer, it wasnt 1 message, but all messages.

Comment: UDP should only be used for streaming data, usually in real-time, when it's "okay" if you don't receive a small portion of it. For example, watching a video on YouTube. Another way to put it: When it's more important for things to happen in a particular order at particular times than it is for all things to happen with a guarantee.

Comment: @JerryDodge yeah but if i would use TCP then that would complicate alot my program, becouse currently im using Broadcast and only the computer that needs to answer answers :), then its just how UDP work, its a pity tho but well ty every1

Comment: Now we found aditional information, the computer that doesnt send/read UDP messages had a diferent DNS, could that be the problem? but it doesnt make sense becouse i use a Broadcast which goes 255.255.255.255 no DNS is needed for that. Maybe any1 can explain me this, Thank you.

Comment: @vexen If the host you're sending data to is an IP Address instead of a Domain Name, then DNS cannot be the issue. However IPv6 could be...

Comment: All im doing is sending a UDP Broadcast to my local network, thats why i cant understand why it should not work, a bit confused at the moment becouse we cant find why it does that, the computer had the DNS of Google which is 8.8.8.8 and all others had the router DNS 192.168.1.1 and still as im doing a UDP Broadcast over Port 50000 and the other one was reading at the same port